# How does a nodejs app retrieve it's own memory usage?

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs app, is there a module or a function that returns the current memory usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> process.memoryUsage()
{ rss: 7827456,
  heapTotal: 2525472,
  heapUsed: 1542704 }
```

Comment: A quick way to see the total memory usage of your app in megabytes is: `process.memoryUsage().rss / (1024 * 1024)`